# Integrating a product of three Spherical Harmonics

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, special-functions

The following command is returned unevaluated. The answer is [well known](https://dlmf.nist.gov/34.3.E22) to be related to Wigner's 3j Symbol which is also a defined function in Mathematica.

```
   Integrate[ 
    SphericalHarmonicY[l, -m, θ, ϕ] SphericalHarmonicY[1, 0, θ, ϕ] *
     SphericalHarmonicY[l + 1, m, θ, ϕ] Sin[θ],
    {ϕ, 0, 2 π}, {θ, 0, π}]
```

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as Mathematica code instead of images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: Your `Y_1` is undefined (for instance).

Comment: Try to add constraints for `m` and `l`, and/or substitute their definition in terms of the associate Legendre polynomials and complex exponentials...

Comment: Adding the usual constraints on m and l does not make any difference. I don't see why I should have to write SphericalHarmonics in terms of Legendre polynomials, that is something the algorithm has to do internally.